# Codeigniter RESTful API - fetch data from MySQL and pass it as JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter, backbone.js

I have a basic Codeigniter setup and I want to fetch specific data from my MySQL database and pass it as JSON data so I can use it in my Backbone frontend. Right now I'm kind of in a dead end, I dont know how to manage it, so I hope i can get some help here.

In my Codeigniter applications folder, and then in my model folder i have:

```
<?php
  Class category_model extends CI_Model
  {

    var $table_name = 'category';
    var $primary_key = 'id';

   function get_all_categories()
   {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table_name);
    return $this->db->get();    
   }

}
?>
```

Then in my controlelr folder, I created an API folder which contains my category controller, category.php:

```
<?php

 include(APPPATH.'./libraries/REST_Controller.php');

 class category extends REST_Controller {

 function index_get() {
    $this->load->model('category_model');
    $data=$this->get('name');
    $this->response($data); 
 }

}

?>
```

This gives me `false` in the Browser...

How do I solve this?

Comment: are you using any library ? Did you check it by directly passing the url to browser

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA yes, I use the REST_Controller.php library... How do I check if I pass it directly to the browser?

Comment: say you are using ajax than sometimes it is difficult to understand what is happening. so my suggestion put the url directly to the browser and go step by step debug line by line say for example you are calling this model in the controller `$this->load->model('category_model');` do this `exit(get_class($this->load->model('category_model')));` and see whether the model is loading also turn on error reporting and error logging which will save a lot of time while debugging

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA ok when I do `exit(get_class($this->load->model('category_model')));` and then enter `http://localhost/myproject/ci/index.php/api/category/` - the browser only displays `category` - Hmm, I'm not using ajax by the way...

Comment: this is just an example how I debug go line by line